# Which Amazon Machine Image to choose - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, web-hosting

I was looking for a little advice on which machine image to choose using amazon EC2.  It seems Linux and Ubuntu are the most popular.  What is the disadvantages or advantages of choosing one or the other?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it would depend on your experience with Linux.  If you are new to Linux, I guess I would start with Ubuntu.  If you run in to trouble it is quite well prevalent and there are a lot of tutorials, forums and search results that you can more then likely learn from.  So, it should be easy for you to use.  It looks like Ubuntu would be no cost to use.  In regards to Amazon Linux, it looks pretty good as well.  I haven't tried it, but from what I read on Amazon's site it looks like it provides everything you would need and it is free.  It uses yum to install packages, so the syntax is different.  You probably could find help or get other questions answered on Amazon's forums.  Between the two if I had to choose I would go with Ubuntu, it's free and you can find a lot of information on it.  So it should be easy to get up and running.  In terms of support I would say both seem to be equal.  I am not sure you would have too much trouble finding a package you would need for Ubuntu and I can't imagine Amazon would not be actively supporting their Linux distro.  Hope this helps.

Mike Riley

Comment: I'd go Ubuntu as well. I would use an LTS version (long term stable) which is supported for 5 years.  You will find WAY more info online to help when you hit an issue.